# How to duplicate target from Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

Seem like this feature was removed from xcode 5 ?

Prior to xcode5, it is easy to duplicate any target via clicking on the target, choose "duplicated blabla", then you will get it.

But for xcode5 , where is this hiding ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Select your project in the left nav. In the main content area at the top, you have a row that is like a file navigator. Then the second row, right under the first, in the very left there is a little square arrow thing.  That hides/shows the project and targets list.

Comment: *groans*, why do they go to such lengths to hide what you need? Thank you very much

Comment: an image would be more understanding

Comment: NOTE: You would probably want to change the "Product name" -> Go to the "Build settings" in this target and search for "Product name".

Answer (score 35):

**Step1:** Select the (blue) project icon in Xcode and open project setting page.

[image: Xcode Proj settings]

**Step2:** Click on the black arrow icon and explore the targets

[image: XCode Proj setting 2]

Step 3: Duplicate your target by selecting the target and press "cmd+D" keys. You can rename as you like.

Enjoy!!

Comment: Screenshots make this so much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is the screenshot from xcode 6:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's still there - right click on target or use `CMD + D` shortcut after selecting target

Comment: I'm missing something, because I don't see this option.  You're right clicking on the target in the project navigator, or somewhere else?

Comment: http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/images/duplicate-target-in-xcode.jpg I still have it here in my Xcode 5.

Comment: That's a screenshot of XCode 4.x, not XCode 5.  Go to the menu Xcode -> About XCode to see what version you're on.

Comment: Yeah maybe this is from 4.0 but anyways I have the same in 5 :)

Comment: it IS still there in 5 but the whole 4 vs 5 mixup in this answer makes it a little 'weird'